# Angular2+ project structure against the domain scope

Tags: angular, architecture

If I use multiple Angular applications to have a proper structure for my project, will that be good or bad? I am creating an application that can be used as a transport management system or hotel management system individually or as a travel management system as a combination of the above two systems including few other components.

So, is it ok to create multiple Angular applications that will redirect from one to the other when it comes to travel solutions but work as independent client apps when they are active, like transport or hotel management systems? is this a good architecture/approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say there’s not really any one right answer to this. It really depends how closely related the different variations on your application are.

If they can be used in combination as a single app for travel management then it sounds like perhaps having it as one app works.

Alternatively having multiple apps can be easier to manage, if their functionality is quite different and not related.